# How to cancel an activity inside a Workflow hosted by WorkflowApplication

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to cancel a long running activity while still keep the whole workflow alive. The workflow itself is hosted in WorkflowApplication.

The real user case is we've got a long running activity which polls the price from an external web service, and once it gets the price the activity should complete and the workflow will move to its next step. However, the price is something nice to have but not mandatory, so in some cases we want to cancel the polling activity and let the WF carry on its execution.

So the question is how can I notify a running workflow to cancel (actually skip) its current activity.. if this is not possible at all, can someone please share your thoughts and point me the right direction to achieve this goal.

Thanks a lot.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Pick activity. Use one PickBranch trigger to poll for the price and add a skip polling bookmarked activity to the other branch. Whatever branch completes first continue and the other will be canceled.